# Stages at which haram things are allowed

Tags: halal-haram

Islam strictly prohibited to eat haram things but what are the stages at which haram things would be allowed to eat??

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the stackexchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your question: The answer is clearly given in the Qur'an ([6:145](https://legacy.quran.com/6/145)). So please clarify what you mean by stages and why this verse might not answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many scenario that you are allowed to eat a Haram food,
for Example:

1. when you are going to die from starvation, you can eat to stay alive, but not more.
2. when you are forced to do. there is no sin for you if you are disagree in your heart.
3. if you did not know you are eating a Haram food.
4. for saving somebody else life.
5. if you are not conscious ( for example if you are sleeping and sombodey put wine in your mouth.

...